# Assigning a spin button to view multiple images using image control

Tags: vba, excel

Below is code from module, whenever I select a row of list box it shows the image with path which is available on list-box index (lisRow, X) on my image control box, I am looking for a solution where I will be able to change value x to 1,2,3 or 4 using a spin button. (image path is currently on column B for multiple images it will take cell C, D or E.. so I will be able to see multiple images on image control)

```
'------------------------------------------------------
Sub ListBox_Click()
LisRow = UserForm2.ListBox2.ListIndex
PictureName = UserForm2.ListBox2.List(LisRow, X)

With UserForm2
  .txt_LastName.Value = .ListBox2.List(LisRow, 0)
  .txt_FirstName.Value = .ListBox2.List(LisRow, X)
  .Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(PictureName)

End With
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You should (1) [edit] your tags and make clear if you use `vb.net` **OR** `vba` **OR** `vb6` these 3 are totally different languages and you need to decide for one of them. (2) You should show what you already tried to achieve your goal.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and do not spam tags.  Each comes with a little text indicating what each is used for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the listbox change event, then you can use the spin button to change the listbox.

```
 Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("S:\Stairs\Stair Pics\" & ListBox1)
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    ListBox1.ListIndex = SpinButton1.Value
End Sub
```